как написать куки для сайта чтобы не вылетало с личного кабинета
Всем привет!
Это мой index.php
<?php
function split_url()
{
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : "home";
    $url = explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    return $url;
}

//create root variable
$root = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$root = trim(str_replace("index.php", "", $root),"/");

define("ROOT", $root . "/");

$URL = split_url();

if(file_exists($URL[0] . ".php")){
    require($URL[0] . ".php");
}else{
    require("404.php");
}

// Добавление скриптов
?>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffb308"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/android/android-launchericon-512-512.png">
<script>
  if (typeof navigator.serviceWorker !== 'undefined') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  }
</script>
<script>
document.cookie = 'element=caesium; max-age=95200168';
</script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icons/logo.ico" height="100%">

Дело в том что пользователь вылетает с личного кабинета каждый раз? Может я что-то неправильно пишу? Не подскажете?
Это мой .htacces файл
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 17280000
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 17280000


Ну допустим вот вы записали куки document.cookie... А дальше где в коде место, с помощью которого вы управляете кукой конкретного пользователя и проверяете его конкертные данные, чтобы он "не вылетал"? на основе чего должен сервер понять, нужно "вылететь" или остаться? .................... ну а в целом: может имеет смысл стартовать сессию?
